# SQL Server : get access to linked server through linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have SQL Server 2008 with linked server, for example Server1. Usually I execute queries like

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Server1,1444].[DBName].[dbo].[Table1]
```

But this time my target table is stored at different server. This server is linked on Server1 like Server2. So, DBA of Server1 gave me a this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Server2].[DB].[dbo].[My_table]
```

On Server1 this query runs without troubles, but when I try to run it on my own server like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Server1,1444].[Server2].[DB].[dbo].[My_table]
```

it shows me an error message, because I'm trying to query one linked server through other linked server.

My question is: how can I execute my query to that Server2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found solution

```
SELECT *  
FROM openquery([Server1,1444], 'SELECT* FROM [Server2].[DB].[dbo].[My_table]')
```